# Public key of a website as seen in the browser vs using openssl command

Tags: ssl, openssl, public-key-encryption

When I see the public key of say google.com in Chrome browser, I see a 256 bytes value as below:

[image: public key certificate for google.com]

When I fetch the public key using openssl command, the value is an alphanumeric string:

Command:

```
openssl s_client -connect google.com:443 | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout
```

Output (only public key):

```
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAqgFRiImAfGWowkJ7FfD+
W27ms/bDJ85XrhneaTzJ3U8mo0z+9k2udrK4FJSHK0cZIwJ8ep4NnyL5/60eC1/N
hDS3CsLvzla7dFxNh38TlEZnhTH+Kg/r9KtMea3T+GzZXGU1bmL9udX22SkvsRnr
owpqAasWaIh9r3y1+ag2LD8fLSM4xvsCOyeywq0CmL+7aYcH7oKWY38EzZk7mgo/
n2YOrB10jVDnKgQRtesIepY0d4fwILYXaZRhlllRHjRXBrp+7EeVkEhF/Aav03pA
Hhvk07upsXZEE3NqOCw7mObtaB/rCc2hfmhxMNHFP+V8rlxOzbaErXwbHfx6CCv4
XwIDAQAB
```

My questions are:

- Is this an hashed value of the above?
- Or an encrypted value?
- What is the role of the signature (another 256 bytes value) as shown in the browser?
- Is there any command line utility to convert between the two representations?

Comment: This is not a programming question

Comment: To get something closer to what you see in chrome use openssl x509 -in cert.pem -text